# background fade leaving focus on popup form/element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have searched and searched for what I thought was a common practice on the web.  Im looking for a simple solution (css, jquery, etc) to make a form appear in the center of the screen when a button is clicked.  I want the background to fade out a bit to leave the focus on the new element/div.  I have played with opacity, but it seems there isn't very good solutions that leaves the form in the middle from being faded as well.  I have seen it, so I know it's doable.  Any help is WAY appreciated!

Comment: You can just use two different containers, one of which is a `position : fixed` background overlay at 0.8 opacity (or whatever), and the other contains your form.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a "modal" popup or a "lightbox".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is a "modal popup window" then the following [resources](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial) [may](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/) [interest](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com) and particularly the [Dialog - Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) example which does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[This css/javascript solution](http://www.pat-burt.com/web-development/how-to-do-a-css-popup-without-opening-a-new-window/) allows any content to be displayed in the popup. Worked like a charm for me.